# How to run programs in Python 3.5 on Mac OS X 10.11 "El Capitan"?

Tags: python, macos

I installed Python 3.5 on the latest OS X but when I run python in Terminal it is still version 2.7. How do I run apps using 3.5?

Comment: Where is it installed?  Is there a `python3` command available?

Comment: Well that was easy.... haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first  thing to check when you installed Python3.5 is it setup correctly like environment variables, $PATH all that.

next run these commands.

```
which python
which python3.5
```

if the second one works then you can make a symlink to it and it should all be good to go. The reason why your installation still uses python 2.7 is due to the fact that the command python points to python 2.7 which came bundled with all mac OS.

To run python 3.5 just type

```
python3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice, use `pyenv` to control the version of python you want running at any time.   http://amaral-lab.org/resources/guides/pyenv-tutorial

`pyenv` will give you the ability to switch back and forth between any version of python available

Also, with `pyenv`:

- you don't need to modify scripts to have odd named python's like `python3` or `python2.7`
- You won't be supprised when OSX drops or changes what the base `python` version is.

Comment: Will this run on OSX?

Comment: @austinthesing yup.  Any *nux based OS.

Comment: @austinthesing it's available in homebrew `brew search pyenv`

Comment: he would have to install homebrew first to do that

Comment: @Seekheart  Yeah, If he's doing development on a mac I just assumed he'd have brew, but that's a valid point.  If for some reason someone didn't want to use brew, they could build and install it manually.

Comment: @Ray he could also just like I said in my answer, install py3 and then symlink it to "python"

Comment: @Seekheart sure, you can manually manage a bunch of symlinks, but that doesn't scale well.   Also, it doesn't ensure OSX won't change the base versions of python without knowing. `pyenv` is a more elegant and gives total control (in fact it works by symlinks)

Comment: @Ray agreed it doesn't scale well